# Элементы массивов в Unity

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Доброго времени суток.

Имеются некоторые улучшения, каждый из которых в свою очередь имеет 5-10 уровней. Как сделать так, чтобы при покупке первого уровня он деактивировался, а второй становился доступным для приобретения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вариант, можно в одно место установить, скажем, кнопки с разным уровнем, и по нажатию на каждую из них скрывать купленную и делать активной другую. Думаю, можно как-то грамотнее через массивы? :)

Comment: Реализовать саму покупка как класс. Запихнуть все покупки скажем в список `List<T>` и классу приделать атрибут `level`. И потом приобретя какой то именно класс, вы сможете делать с его атрибутом level все что угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Храните где-нибудь текущее количество купленных улучшений данного типа :)
Например, у вас будет массив `Upgrade[]` из n элементов и переменная `_curentUpgrade`, которая хранит количество купленных улучшений. Тогда следующий цикл прохода по доступным кнопкам сделает то, что вам нужно:

```
    Button[] _buttons;

    int _curentUpgradeLevel;

    void UpdateInteractable()
    {
        int count = _buttons.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var button = _buttons[i];
            button.interactable = i == _curentUpgradeLevel;
        }
    }
```

Пока улучшений не было - активна только кнопка с индексом 0 - т.е. первая в списке. При покупке вызывайте что-то вроде:

```
    void BuyUpgrade()
    {
        _curentUpgradeLevel++;
        UpdateInteractable();
    }
```

Когда улучшения закончатся - все кнопки будут неактивны :)